# PL-SQL Insert records in a collection table of objects

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have this table of object collection declared at schema level:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "T_ATTRIBUTEPAGE_ATTRIBUTELIST" IS TABLE OF o_ATTRIBUTEPAGE_ATTRIBUTELIST;
```

and `o_ATTRIBUTEPAGE_ATTRIBUTELIST` is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "O_ATTRIBUTEPAGE_ATTRIBUTELIST" IS OBJECT (
    WizAttrEditID           NUMBER,
    InternalIndex           NUMBER,
    DimensionObjectID       NUMBER,
    AttributeName           VARCHAR2(50),
    AttributeLabel          VARCHAR2(50),
    AttributeType           NUMBER,
    AttributeLength         VARCHAR2(50),
    MandatoryAttribute      NUMBER,
    ReadOnly                NUMBER,

    Name                VARCHAR2(2000),
    Num                 NUMBER,

    IsModified          NUMBER,
    Colour              NUMBER);
```

I want to insert one item in the collection and I'm trying to do so like this:

```
ls_attribute_list := attributelist(1950053739,1,3, "PROTECTION_ROLE", "Protection Role",5,1,1,0, "Path A", 1, 1,0);
```

where `ls_attribute_list` and `attributelist` are of type `T_ATTRIBUTEPAGE_ATTRIBUTELIST` but I'm getting:

> Error: PLS-00316: PL/SQL TABLEs must use a single index

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`attributelist(i);` is used to get the `i`<sup>th</sup> element of the existing `attributelist` collection. You are passing multiple arguments which is syntactically invalid and Oracle assumes you are trying to get an element from the collection and just passing too many arguments so throws the `PLS-00316` exception.

If you want to create a new list with one element then use the names of the types:

```
ls_attribute_list := T_ATTRIBUTEPAGE_ATTRIBUTELIST( -- Nested table collection type
  O_ATTRIBUTEPAGE_ATTRIBUTELIST(                    -- Object type
    1950053739,                                     -- Object attributes
    1,                                              -- ...
    3,
    'PROTECTION_ROLE',
    'Protection Role',
    5,
    1,
    1,
    0,
    'Path A',
    1,
    1,
    0
  )                                                 -- Complete the object
);                                                  -- Complete the collection
```

*(Note: String literals are surrounded by single `'` quotes.)*

> I want to insert one item in the collection

You can do this using:

```
attributelist.EXTEND( 1 );                          -- Append one NULL element
attributelist( attributelist.LAST )                 -- See Note below
  := O_ATTRIBUTEPAGE_ATTRIBUTELIST(                 -- Object type
    1950053739,                                     -- Object attributes
    1,                                              -- ...
    3,
    'PROTECTION_ROLE',
    'Protection Role',
    5,
    1,
    1,
    0,
    'Path A',
    1,
    1,
    0
  );                                                -- Complete the object
```

*(Note: If the collection is dense then you can use either `collectionvalue.COUNT` or `collectionvalue.LAST` to get the highest indexed element of the collection; however, if the collection is sparse then `COUNT < LAST` and you can only use `collectionvalue.LAST`.)*

Comment: Great, works perfectly, is there a way to insert the element at a certain position in the list, if the list is not empty?

Comment: `attributelist(i) := O_ATTRIBUTEPAGE_ATTRIBUTELIST( ... );` will overwrite the `i`th element.

Comment: and without overriding it, only if I move each element after the one that I want to add?

Comment: If you want to insert an element into the middle of a collection then create a new collection and add the `1`st through `i-1`th items then append the new element then append the remaining elements from the initial list.

Comment: Or you could extend the existing collection by 1 and then do `FOR n IN REVERSE i+1 .. attributelist.LAST LOOP attributelist(n) := attributelist(n-1); END LOOP;` and then overwrite the `i`th element.